# How to detect path in Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make something like here: [AngularJS show div based on url/condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114854/angularjs-show-div-based-on-url-condition)

```
<span id="page-locator" *ngIf="location.path() == '/overview'">test</span>
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I achieve this in Angular2?

Thanks.

Comment: if you are looking for current page then check this link: H[ow do I get the absolute path of the current page in Angular 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517183/how-do-i-get-the-absolute-path-of-the-current-page-in-angular-2)

Comment: I'm trying to make if work with ngIf.. but thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the path of the Angular router, correct? If so, you can inject the `Router` service into your component and use that in your view:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class SomeComponent {
    constructor(public router: Router) { }
}
```

Then in your component template you can access the current router url via:

```
<span id="page-locator" *ngIf="router.url === '/overview'">test</span>
```

Comment: You could use `*ngIf="router.url.indexOf('/overview') >= 0"` in that scenario to determine if the url contains the route as well.

Comment: How the... did I forget about indexOf()... thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

`window.location` is where you can get your information!

for an absolute path you can go this way :

```
constructor(location:Location) {
  console.log(location.prepareExternalUrl(location.path()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution :

```
location: any;
constructor(private _router: Router) { 
      _router.events.subscribe((data:any) => { this.location = data.url; });
}
```

The data is an object and we need the url property contained in that object.

```
<span id="page-locator" *ngIf="location == '/overview'">test</span>
```